# How to check for all the links on the page and check the values of 'rel' and 'target' attributes as well as the destination status (200) in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, affiliate

I'm trying to find all the affiliate links on the page and the links should have the ff: attributes: `target="_blank"` `rel="nofollow noopener sponsored"` also I need to check the status of each link. and it should be `200`.

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Are you looking to do this for only one page or multiple?

Comment: multiple pages. maybe 10 pages.

Answer (score 3):

If you can add a `data-testid` attribute to your affiliate links, that would make query cleaner and easier to maintain. Otherwise:

```
cy.get('[target=_blank] [rel="nofollow noopener sponsored"]') // could be simplier with data-test-ids for affiliate links only
  .each( $affiliateLink => {

      // check links have attributes
      expect($affiliateLink).to.have.attr('target', '_blank')
      expect($affiliateLink).to.have.attr('rel', 'nofollow noopener sponsored')

      // make a request to presumably external domains
      cy.request($affiliateLink.prop('href')) // may need to pass some options for request
        .its('status')
        .should('eq', 200)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Using `each()` you can iterate over all the links and then check whether they are broken or not and also check that the links have `target="_blank"` and `rel="nofollow noopener sponsored"`.

```js
cy.get('a').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele)
    .invoke('attr', 'href')
    .then((href) => {
      cy.request(href).then((response) => {
        expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
      })
    })
  cy.wrap($ele)
    .should('have.attr', 'target', '_blank')
    .and('have.attr', 'rel', 'nofollow noopener sponsored')
})
```

Now, If you just want to check that the links have the attributes `target` and `rel` and then check whether those links return 200, then you can do like:

```js
cy.get('a').each(($ele) => {
  if (
    $ele.attr('target') == '_blank' &&
    $ele.attr('rel') == 'nofollow noopener sponsored'
  ) {
    cy.request($ele.attr('href').trim()).its('status').should('eq', 200)
  }
})
```

Comment: maybe not all the links, coz not all links will have the same attributes (navbar links). My focus is on the affiliate links on the page.

Comment: So you want to test that when the links have target and rel attribute then it should be 200 ?

Comment: pretty much, yes.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate your help